# Get Specific part of the string of a spinner

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner

I have a spinner populated by mysql Database:

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

 final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> map;

 for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
 JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

 map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("customerID", c.getString("id_bus"));
 map.put("name", c.getString("bus_line"));
 map.put("phone", c.getString("bus_number"));
 MyArrList.add(map);

 }
 SimpleAdapter sAdap;
 sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, MyArrList,  R.layout.activity_show,
 new String[] {"name", "phone"}, new int[] {R.id.ColName, R.id.ColTel});
 spin.setAdapter(sAdap);
```

know if i get the selected value by using this:

```
String newCategory = spin.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

what i get is:

```
{customerID=1 , phone=1001 , name=JAM }
```

but all i want to get is "1001"
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spin.getSelectedItem()` returns Selected object of Spinner from adapter.

So in your case it would be, a `HashMap<String, String>` object so just cast it and **get required values using key** from HashMap.

Like,

```
Map<String, String> selectedMap = (HashMap<String, String>) spin.getSelectedItem();
String phoneNumber = selectedMap.get("phone");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need an ArrayList of String with your "phone" values for your adapter :

```
final ArrayList<String> myArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
   JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
   myArrList.add(c.getString("bus_number"));
}
```